# Trouble aliasing ctl-x-map, C-x 8 insert command?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys, self-insert-command, key-translation-map

I'm reading the beginning of the Emacs manual on [inserting text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html). It says you can run `C-x 8 [` to insert a left single curly quote. That works.

In my `init.el` I have this:

```
(define-key global-map [(control t)] ctl-x-map)
```

I like that because I use a Dvorak keyboard layout, so `C-t` is easy to type. Usually that line takes commands that start with `C-x` and makes them available starting with `C-t` too. But it's failing with this `C-x 8`.  If I do: `C-t 8 [`, it get a beep and nothing.

In contrast I can do both `C-x b` and `C-t b` to switch to a buffer.

Why does my `define-key` attempt work for most `C-x` commands but not `C-x 8`.

I'm running GNU Emacs 27.2 on macOS 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-x 8 [` and similar are defined in a different keymap, `iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map`.

What you need is this:

```lisp
(define-key key-translation-map "\C-t8" 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Translation Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) for more info.